# R-mlr: How to pass extra parameters to predict while using resampling?

Tags: r, machine-learning, mlr

Is there a way to pass parameters to the predict call when using resampling in mlr? E.g. predict.coxph has an extra parameter "reference", which i want to change when using resampling, but extra-parameters for resampling seem to be for the learner only.

I have for now just extracted the models and the test data from the resampling object and apply the prediction myself, but that seems clumsy somehow.

Is there a better solution?
Thanks!

Comment: You don't access the predict functions in mlr directly, so unless the specific parameter is supported by mlr, you'll have to do it this way.

Comment: thanks for the info!